# How do you get subpaths to work for create-react-app in minikube?

Tags: reactjs, docker, kubernetes, create-react-app, minikube

Figured this would be straight forward, but apparently this is not the case.

I have two CRA microservices running at:

- `/`
- `/admin`

`minikube ip` is `192.168.64.5`, so the full routes should be `192.168.64.5/` and `192.168.64.5/admin` in browser. The `Dockerfile.dev` just has each being started with `npm start`.

The root route works fine, but the `/admin` I can't get the static files to serve correctly for the life of me... spent several hours on it. All I get back is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`, which stems from the static files not being served correctly.

That being said, when I do `npm build`, or just go to `localhost:3000/admin`, the web application  is served correctly. `npm build` is obviously not ideal for development. Using `localhost` just circumvents the cluster routing, so issues that could have been caught in dev, will now show-up in staging. I'll have to go that route if I can't get this working though.

I've tried the `"homepage:"` and `basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}`, but it is not resolving the issue:

```
# package.json 

{
  "name": "admin",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "/admin",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "history": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

```
# index.js

import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";

export const history = createBrowserHistory({
  basename: process.env.PUBLIC_URL
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/">
        <App />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);


serviceWorker.unregister();
```

```
# index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!-- <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" /> -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <base href="%PUBLIC_URL%/">
    <!-- <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" /> -->
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <!-- <link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json" /> -->
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Also, tried with `.env` `PUBLIC_URL`, but has the same effect as `"homepage":`.

The [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/) says:

> Normally, Create React App ignores the hostname.

But apparently there is something it doesn't like about `minikube ip` and the cluster. Seems like this would be a pretty common requirememt, so there is probably a straight forward solution I'm just overlooking.

Any suggestions for getting this working?

```
# ingress.yaml

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
  name: ingress-service-dev
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /admin/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: admin-cluster-ip-service-dev
              servicePort: 4001
          - path: /?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: client-cluster-ip-service-dev
              servicePort: 3000
          - path: /api/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: api-cluster-ip-service-dev
              servicePort: 5000
```

Comment: I am assuming the error is a 404. So HTML is bein returned and causing the error. I am not sure what route will be sent to CRA from the SubPath. Try putting a wildcard route on the Admin CRA App just to get the ball rolling.

Comment: @GarryTaylor Thanks for the help, I did try `<Route path="/*">` and `<Route path="*">`, but running into the same issue. And to confirm, that is correct, it is apparently not finding the JS assets and just returning the index.html causing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, apparently the issue was `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1` in the `ingress.yaml`. I commented it out and it started working.

You can refer to the `index.html`, `index.js`, and `package.json` above as those are unchanged.

The final `ingress.yaml` I have is:

```
# ingress.yaml

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
  name: ingress-service-dev
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /admin/
            backend:
              serviceName: admin-cluster-ip-service-dev
              servicePort: 4001
          - path: /api/
            backend:
              serviceName: api-cluster-ip-service-dev
              servicePort: 5000
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: client-cluster-ip-service-dev
              servicePort: 3000
```

Nothing breaking so far and everything working as expected.